# ColdFusion forgets variable within 1 line

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

My company works with ColdFusion and has had this problem in different variations for years now. It's time to get it solved.

The scenario is very simple:

```
<cfparam name="session.check" default="0">
<cfif NOT isDefined('session.check') OR 
      session.check IS 0>
    <cfset ok=1>
</cfif>
```

Now ColdFusion throws an error:

> Element CHECK is undefined in SESSION. 
>   The error occurred on line 18.

For those who can read something out of it, here's the detailed stack trace:

> coldfusion.runtime.UndefinedElementException: Element CHECK is undefined in SESSION. at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.resolveCanonicalName(CfJspPage.java:1694) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._resolve(CfJspPage.java:1612) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._resolveAndAutoscalarize(CfJspPage.java:1747) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._resolveAndAutoscalarize(CfJspPage.java:1740) at
>   cfindex2ecfm123677868._factor9(C:\path\index.cfm:18) at ...

If cfparam is used or just a cfset doesn't really matter. Also, this is NOT a simplified example, this very error occured on our server. With no single line between the variable being set and read.

We're running ColdFusion 8.0.1.195765.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume the "checkIS" is a typo?

Comment: Yes, updated the post. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Also, do you have a structclear(session) anywhere in the app?

Comment: Somewhere, yes. But it is near to impossible that a user may trigger that part of the code at the same time as the example code; and compared to that, correctly timing the two site calls so the StructClear on site 2 is being processed right between the cfparam and the cfif check on site 1 is the least problem.

Comment: 1) Has this ever been reproduced during testing, 2) How often does it occur, 3) In what situation or type of requests is structclear(session) triggered? This error is even less likely to happen than you think due to a race condition because the OR operator would short circuit. If "NOT IsDefined" is TRUE then the "session.check IS 0" code would never be hit.

Comment: You mentioned in another comment that this has happened to non-session (local) variables. If this has happened to non-shared scope variables then something is not right with the computer, jvm or info available about the problem.

Comment: 1) No, never ever.
2) For one of our bigger projects that I am currently monitoring, a few times a day (3-20 times). I don't have access to statistics, but it's a medium sized online shop.
3) StructClear only happens when a user submitted an order. Which of course accounts only for a very small part of site calls and therefore processed code.

Comment: As for the non-session variables: I am pretty sure I observed that, yes. I will have a hard mail finding those error reports and those scenarios were less obvious than this one, which is why I didn't go into detail on that.

Comment: have you tried it as `isdefined("session.check")` I have had issues using the single quote in as isdefined. for the most part I only use `StructKeyExists(session,'check')` I would try both of those options and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: mrbusche: Thanks for that hint, I have yet to try that out, tomorrow. Although that existance check SHOULD be redundant anyway as the variable is being set a line above.

Comment: Can you put a try/catch around line 18, and serialise the session scope and log it (or if appropriate, just dump it to screen).  Is the session scope empty, or is just that variable that's AWOL?

Comment: It's not somehow a case sensitivity issue is it?  CF is usually pretty good about it, but it's not something silly like for some reason it can't match `session['check'] == session['CHECK'] == session.check` is it?  @AdamCameron's comment about serialising will help see that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `structKeyExists` instead of `isDefined`

```
<cfif NOT structKeyExists(session, 'check') OR 
      session.check IS 0>
    <cfset ok=1>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks but the variable should be defined anyway. The isDefined was just an additional indicator that something is wrong, basically.

BTW, this also happened to non-session (local) variables. I have no current example of that so I was sticking to that one.

Answer (score 1):

2 guesses here.... First, you might be fooled by the line number in error. Look above line 18 - above the code you pasted in the stack or order of execution. Look for another "check" reference.

Meanwhile, this code:

```
<cfparam name="session.check" default="0">
<cfif NOT isDefined('session.check') OR 
      session.check IS 0>
    <cfset ok=1>
</cfif>
```

While ok... includes "NOT isDefined('session.check')" ... which given the cfparam ahead of it is superflous. Cfparam should *guarantee* that the var exists so you should not need the "isDefined". I'm guessing it was put in because of the error.

Guess Number 2

Depending on the application this could also be some sort of race problem - especially if using frames or ajax. Try bracketing the code with a CFLOCK for the session scope:

```
<cflock scope="session" timeout="4">
   <cfparam name="session.check" default="0">
   <cfif NOT isDefined('session.check') OR 
         session.check IS 0>
       <cfset ok=1>
   </cfif>
</cflock>
```

This would insure that *this* code would run on an unaltered session - no guarantees on other code that might hit the session.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to declare a timeout of your session?
This one times out in 12 hrs...

```
 <!--- Create the application --->
 <cfapplication name="MyApp" clientmanagement="Yes"
                sessionmanagement="Yes"
                sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,12,0,0)#"
                applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,12,0,0)#">
        <!--- 
        #CreateTimeSpan(days,hours,minutes,seconds)#
        --->

 <cfparam name="session.check" default="0">
```

Comment: Session timeout is set to 1 hour:

`<cfapplication name="app" clientmanagement="Yes" sessionmanagement="Yes" sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,1,0,0)#" clientstorage="Cookie"/>`

Comment: Did you just put in the value "app" for the name attribute as an example, or is that the actual name used across multiple CF applications?

Comment: What about application timeout?

Comment: Dan: I just put it in, it is unique and actually happens to be the ONLY project running on that specific server.

Merle: Not set specifically, default is 2 days. Keep in mind the problem happens between two lines of code and assuming the isDefined check works even within a sole cfif condition check.

Answer (score 0):

Check and ensure your CFApplication name is UNIQUE and distinctive.  Best Practices usually end up hashing the current directory to ensure this but you could also try adding a version number too to be absolutely sure. e.g:

```
<CFAPPLICATION name="myApp_0001_#hash(getCurrentTemplatePath())#">
```

A distressed server that is restarting constantly too can drop sessions as well but the previous reason is probably the most common cause of this...especially in a shared hosting environment.